# Proof of bijective bounded linear operator map closed set to closed set

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to prove a bijective, bounded linear operator $T$ of Hilbert space $H$ maps closed set to closed set.

Here is my attempt, let $A$ be a closed subset of $H$, then $H-A$ is open, by open mapping theorem, $T(H-A)$ is open, since it is bijective, $T(H-A)=H-T(A)$, which is open, so $T(A)$ is closed.

Is the argument correct?

Comment: Yes, it is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your approach is perfect and your reasoning also :

A bijective bounded linear map between two Banach spaces have bounded inverse. Hence becomes a homeomorphism and a homeomorphism is a closed map.